# Asterisk, Ignore "Ring Back" from soft phones

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip

Customer calls into my Asterisk Box.
Customer key presses that he wants to talk to an Agent.
Asterisk dials him to Agent.
Agent phone tells Asterisk to "Ring Back".
Agent picks up the call. 
Call Completes.

I need to disable the "Ring Back".  I do not want it to ring at all.
When Agent is using free version of X-Lite, there is a ring.
I have a SDK license from X-Lite, and there is a code line where I can disable the phone from sending the Ring Back code.

Is there a setting in Asterisk where I can tell it to just ignore the Ring Back regardless if it's sent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you not need ringing from phone, you can setup asterisk play musiconhold instead using m(holdclass) param in dial command.

If you want silence, you always can put silence message as moh.